# À propos de l'expression "comment ça marche"

Tags: ordre-des-mots

La position du mot « marche » dans « Comment ça marche la répétition espacée ? » est un peu étonnante pour moi.

Je pensais que ça serait mieux de dire « Comment la répétition espacée marche ? »

Quelle est la différence ? Est-c que les deux sont possibles ?

Answer (score 1):

Il s'agit d'un cas d'emphase, le pronom démonstratif vient centrer et accentuer l'interrogation partielle, qui questionne la manière dont se fera l'action (marcher) via l'adverbe "comment", sur un autre élément :

Comment [ça] marche [la répétition espacée] ?

Les éléments (ça) et (la répétition espacée) partagent la même fonction grammaticale, celle de sujet du verbe (marcher). Pour répondre à vos questions : Oui, les deux constructions sont correctes, la différence réside seulement sur le plan communicatif comme expliqué plus haut, ainsi, on pourrait écrire votre phrase de différentes manières :

- Comment ça marche, la répétition espacée ? (Cas d'emphase)
- Ça marche comment, la répétition espacée ? (Cas d'emphase)
- La répétition espacée, ça marche comment ? (Cas d'emphase)
- La répétition espacée, comment ça marche ? (Cas d'emphase)
- Comment marche la répétition espacée ? (Phrase neutre)
- Comment la répétition espacée marche ? (Phrase neutre)
- Comment ça marche ? (Phrase neutre)
- ...

**Remarque :** J'entends par "neutre" l'absence d'emphase ou d'accentuation d'un des éléments de la phrase.

Comment: _Comment la répétition espacée marche ?_ sonne à tout le moins un peu bizarre. Sans un contexte spécifique, on n'utilise pas cette tournure.

Comment: @Frank bizarre je vous l'accorde, parce qu'elle devrait suivre une tournure interrogative avec une inversion du sujet et un pronom personnel qui renforce celui-ci : `comment la répétition espacée marche-t-elle ?`, mais sur les plans syntaxique et sémantique, elle reste correcte. Dans quel contexte spécifique l'inscririez-vous pour qu'elle soit moins bizarre ?